# How to setup max memory for a redis5.0.5 cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a redis cluster with **4 servers with 24 GB** memory each. Each server has a master and a slave instance running.

**Cluster topology:** (A-->B means A is slave of B)

```
server2 slave-->server1 master
server3 slave-->server2 master
server4 slave-->server3 master
server1 slave-->server4 master
```

These servers are for redis alone, so I can allot upto 22 GB memory for redis.

But I am not sure how to setup `maxmemory` for these instances. Do I need to set it at 11 GB on master and slave each, on each server? Or I need to set it to 22 GB for both servers?

Also, what would be the overall memory available for data on redis, 22*4 = 88GB, or 22 GB only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your master and slave are located on the same server, you should set `maxmemory` to 11GB for each master and slave. Also, the overall memory available for the cluster is `11 * 4 = 44G`.

Comment: Can you also share some resources for the same. Checked in redis documentation, and some other sources that I could find, but it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Alsp, if you're using persistence, you'll need to reserve some of the server's memory for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
redis-cli -h <host_name> -p <port> -a <password> config get maxmemory
redis-cli -h <host_name> -p <port> -a <password> config set maxmemory <Bytes>
redis-cli -h <host_name> -p <port> -a <password> config get maxmemory

# cat your redis.conf to see max memory
cat redis.conf
# you will find redis.conf has old maxmemory
# so you can rewrite redis.conf
redis-cli -h <host_name> -p <port> -a <password> config rewrite
```